# The difference between standard topology and discrete topology (both on $R$)

Tags: general-topology

Is discrete topology finer than the standard topology on $R$?

What I understood is the following

- In discrete topology, we are making every element $x \in R$ an open set. Whereas in the standard topology we are sticking with the previous openness definition defined on $R$

Comment: I don't like the term *finer*. I would say the discrete topology is **larger** than the standard topology.

Comment: The discrete topology is always the largest (and finest) possible topology since each subset is open. Be careful, the sets $\{x\}$ are open, not the elements $x$. The discrete topology is good for a lot of counterexamples.

Comment: In the discrete topology on $\Bbb R,$ the number $x\in \Bbb R$ is NOT an open set. The set $\{x\}$ is an open set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be any set. The discrete topology on $X$ is simply the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and is always the finest/largest topology one can impose on any set.

Also note that in the discrete topology every **singleton** $\{x\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$